# Get the last webpage content when clicking on a button

Tags: python, flask, beautifulsoup, request, python-requests

I am changing a value on a table in my html using bootstable.js and that's going well. Once I click on a submit button to send the modified table to my python in order to use the new values later.
My problem: I am getting the old values

I tried just refreshing the webpage => I am getting the old values

Here's my code :

```
@app.route('/test', methods =['POST'])
Def test():
Page = requests.get(request.url)
Soup= BeautifulSoup(page.content,      'html.parser')
Data = []
Table = soup.find(id='mytable')
Here I use the content
```

Any help please.

Thank you